# How to update multiple columns in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Just out of curiosity, is there a way to say this...

```
user.update_column(:field1, true)
user.update_column(:field2, true)
```

... in one line in Ruby on Rails?

As far as I know an `update_columns` method does not exist...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `update_all` as follows:

```
User.where(:id => user.id).update_all({:field1 => true, :field2 => true})
```

This will generate the following update statement (mysql):

```
UPDATE users SET field1 = 1, field2 = 1 WHERE users.id = <whatever>
```

Callbacks and validations will not be run.

Comment: If your goal is to update the record without changing the updated_at field, this will not work. Otherwise, it's the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

> **Note**: this is only available in ActiveRecord `v4.0.2` and higher:

You can do in this way:

```
update_columns(field1: value, filed2: value)
```

Comment: this is only available in activerecord v4.0.2 and higher:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns

Comment: this only updates single record unlike `update_all` but it skips updating `updated_at` and callbacks

Answer (score 2):

what about doing it like this:

```
user.attributes = attributes
user.save(validate: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need speed you can also call execute directly on AR connection. I used something like this to import large amount of data.

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
email = connection.quote(email)
zip = connection.quote(zip)
connection.execute(%{UPDATE "users" SET "email" = #{email}, "zip" = #{zip} WHERE "users"."id" = #{user.id}})
```

Note that validations and callbacks will not be run.

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25171127/1520775