# Using update_columns in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a shorter way for this in Rails 3?

```
user.update_column(:attribute1, value1)
user.update_column(:attribute2, value2)
user.update_column(:attribute3, value3)
user.update_column(:attribute4, value4)
```

I tried `update_columns` but it's only available in Rails 4.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To be clear, this question doesn't mention wether or not callbacks are needed. Clarification is needed, until then it's safe to assume callbacks are not wanted.

Comment: You asked a question that can not be answered without clarification.  Then you didn't clarify when asked about callbacks.  Not trying to sound rude but please understand when people are trying to help, you should follow up.

Answer (score 34):

Here's a workaround for Rails 3.x:

```
User.where(id: user.id).update_all(attribute1: value1, attribute2: value2, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need speed you can also call execute directly on AR connection. I used something like this to import large amount of data.

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
email = connection.quote(email)
zip = connection.quote(zip)
connection.execute(%{UPDATE "users" SET "email" = #{email}, "zip" = #{zip} WHERE "users"."id" = #{user.id}})
```

Note that validations and callbacks will not be run.

Answer (score -1):

another approach you can take which accomplishes the same thing is this:

```
user.assign_attributes(
  first_name: 'foo',
  last_name: 'bar'
)

user.save(validate: false)
```

NOTE:  You don't have to use the validate false.  However, the #update_column method does skip validations and callbacks.  So if that is what you are looking for, use the validate false.