# How can I write a following sql in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
update table_name set filename = CONCAT(filename, "test") where id = 111
```

How can I write the above SQL with ActiveRecord syntax in Rails ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update multiple columns in Ruby on Rails 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880931/how-to-update-multiple-columns-in-ruby-on-rails-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have model associated with given table, you can do:

```
m = Model.find(111)
m.update_column(:filename, m.filename + 'test')
```

If you want to to update multiple records:

```
Model.update_all('filename = CONCAT(filename, "test")')
```

or limit scope of elements with conditions:

```
Model.where(...).update_all(...)
```

Comment: @krunalshah: Wait, what?  The example SQL in your question suggests that you're only modifying one record.

Comment: We have multiple records with same id in that table.

Comment: @krunalshah - This is extremely confusing, it is rails convention to use `id` as a primary key, you should at least mention it in your question.